# how to create table with sails migrations

Tags: sails.js

I want to create basic crud through sails framework. I had run these command

```
sails new sails_app
sails generate api employee
```

*connection.js*

```
module.exports.connections = {
  mysql: {
    adapter: 'sails-mysql',
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'MyTestPassword123',
    database: 'employeehandbook'
  }
}
```

I hit this url

```
http://localhost:1337/employee/create?name=Brij&email=test@techbrij.com&phone=123-456-7890
```

**OutPut:**

```
{
  "name": "Brij",
  "email": "test@techbrij.com",
  "phone": "123-456-7890",
  "createdAt": "2016-02-24T11:23:32.841Z",
  "updatedAt": "2016-02-24T11:23:32.841Z",
  "id": 1
}
```

Now I checked the database, There is no one table created by sails
Is this create table automatically or will I create it?

or how to run migrations in sails?

Answer (score 1):

You should place your connection at

> config/env/development.js

like that:

```
 models: {
         connection: 'mysql'
     },
```

Answer (score 1):

Tables are created automatically in Sails. This is how you do it:

- In `config/models.js` set `migrate:create`
- In `config/env/development.js` set `connection:'mysql'` (since that's what you named your connection in `config/connections.js`

THEN to create/update tables run `sails lift` which will start your app in development mode, allowing tables to be created. At that point, check if the table has been created (it should exist).

Comment: Here is a relevant link btw: http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/deployment#?set-up-production-database-s-for-your-models